# NameError: undefined local variable or method `watir' for main:Object

Tags: ruby, watir

I am using the following code in irb:

```
irb(main):002:0>driver = watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

But it gives me this error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `watir' for main:Object
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `Watir` must be capitalized - ie `driver = Watir::Browser.new`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to access a nested class, which should refer to capitalised variable names:

```
driver = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

By using the lowercase `watir`, you're looking for a variable `watir` defined in the local scope. You could, for instance, be storing the top level class / module in a variable:

```
watir = Watir
```

And then call the code as you have it, though that's pointless and an antipattern.

Capitalise the first letter as above, and this should work for you.

Edit: as Justin Ko pointed out, it sounds like that is now looking for the correct class, though it needs to be available to the file. Add this to the top and everything should work:

```
require 'watir'
```

Comment: Sorry but now I get new error.
irb(main):001:0> driver = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
NameError: uninitialized constant Watir
        from (irb):1
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'

Comment: @CesarPinto, you need to tell Ruby to include the Watir gem. Add `require "watir"` as the first line.

Comment: @CesarPinto - did this help in the end?